# infinity while loop when have recursive function

Tags: c++, loops, recursion, while-loop

I'm solving a problem. I want a function that returns all ways to make different positive `int` number plus equal to that number, for example 6 will be 1+5 ,2+3+1,2+4 so will be 3
but my solution return infinity loop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int find(int num,int before)
{

    int first=1;
    int count=1;
    int end =num-1;
    if(end-first==0) return count;
    while(end-first!=1&&end-first!=0)
    {
        if(end==before||first==before) continue;
        first++;
        end--;
    }
    before=first;
    return count+find(end,before);
}
int main()
{
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    int x=find(a,1);
    cout<<x;
}
```

i try `cout` "a" in loop and repeat forever. Please help me.

**EDIT: My code just solve a piece of problem, so it not solution, i'll try to close topic, thanks all**

Comment: Once `if(end==before||first==before) continue;` hits there's nothing to break the loop.

Comment: my purpose is to prevent first or end equal to loop, that all, no t to break the loop, thanks for you r suggestion

Answer (score 1):

In this concept `first` will always be *1* and `before` will always be **1** because the `first` is never incremented here as the instruction is not reached.

`first` is initialized by **1** and `before` by **1**, that means `before==first` is true and the loop will ignore all other instructions after `continue`.

and since you are comparing `end==before||first==before` this will always be true, because even when `end==before` is `false` the second test will be true. The test logic of `false||true` is `true`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i dont understand why "first" not increased? and my purpose is in first rescusion, ' before ' will equal to first when first increased in loop, i try to change "||" by && because i want to "not equal 1 or 0 will end loop" but it return infintity loop again,please help me, thanks

Comment: When calling the function `find(a,1);` here `before` has **1** as value.  and inside the function `int first=1;` here first has **1** as value. so the test `first==before` is `true` because `1=1`. and with the instruction `continue` the loop ignores every thing else after. and goes to next iteration.

Comment: I'm going to test your code and find a solution to your idea. But the problem with the loop is that